# Is it possible to identify domain associated with SSL certificate in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ssl, x509

Is it possible to identify domain or domains/wildcard associated with SSL certificate in Javascript (Browser-side)? Given the PEM file?

Comment: Are you asking  if you can extract the CN and subject alternative names from a certificate given as a PEM string inside Javascript? It should be doable in theory since all needed information are inside the PEM data but I don't know if there is a library which helps you do it in an easy way. But essentially it is some base64 decoding and some ASN.1 parsing to get to the data.

Comment: Yeah something like that just to display what domain will be affected when user uploads a SSL

Comment: In this case searching for [javascript parse x509](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+parse+x509) should give you also some libraries to help with the task.